# Programs crash after joining the server into a Domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain, sql-server-2008, server-crashes, application

## UPDATE: Problem solved

*We decided to upgrade the computer from **Windows Server 2008** to **Windows Server 2008 R2**, after reboot, all the problems where fixed. Every app can be executed from domain users. Thanks, I think we can close this question*

## Scenario:

We have a computer running Windows Server 2008 (not promoted as a domain controller) with Microsoft SQL Server 2008 installed. We also have a client-app that connects to the SQL Server and a 3th-party app that connects to SQL Server  for backup jobs. Everything is working as expected. Then we decided to join this server into a Domain (as a member server, we didn't promoted as a DC)...

## Technical Info:

- Microsoft Windows Server 2008 Enterprise  (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4042.0 (X64) Express Edition with Advanced Services (64-bit)

## The problem:

After joining the domain, some applications crash if we log in with **any domain account** (for example the domain Administrator). However, if we log in using **any local account** (for example the local Administrator) we can run all the programs without errors.

We detected the following actions that fails/crash if we are logged with a domain account:

- Executing *Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio*
- Executing our client-app that connects to the SQL Server
- Executing the 3th-party app that connects to SQL Server for backup-jobs
- Trying to repair/reinstall/uninstall *.Net Framework 3.5 SP1* from control panel
- Trying to repair/reinstall/uninstall *.Net Framework 4.5.2* from control panel

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

In the Event Viewer, we find **eventID 1000** with the app crash report:

[image]

If we logoff from the domain account and log in again using the local Administrator account, all the apps below can be executed without errors. All of them

## Things we tried to fix the problem:

- Reinstall .Net Framework
- Install all updates from Windows Updater Center
- Reboot server
- Repairing system errors with: `sfc /SCANNOW`

We can easily reproduce the problem using `runas.exe`:

`runas /user:DOMAIN\Administrator ssms.exe` = **crash**
`runas /user:LOCAL_COMPUTER\Administrator ssms.exe` = **no crash**

We are open to test and report feedback here, hope somebody can help us with this problem.

Comment: Where is the `cscompui.dll` file?

Comment: Please post your resolution as an answer. You can then [mark it accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things I would try:

- Use SysInternal's (Microsoft's) Process Monitor (procmon.exe), setting the filter to "process name IS ssms.exe" and see what it does prior to the crash.  Then re-run with a working user to see what it would do next if all was OK.
- Check the settings in the local security policy
- Use **GPRESULT.EXE /SCOPE user /H c:\<your path>\rsop.html /F** to create an RSoP report to see if group policy is setting anything strange for the domain account
- Confirm that your anti-virus product isn't acting differently with domain accounts

...then review the results before thinking of next steps.

Comment: We decided to upgrade the computer from **Windows Server 2008** to **Windows Server 2008 R2**, after reboot, all the probles where fixed. Every app can be executed from domain users. Thanks, I think we can close this question

Comment: @CET10 This is fixed, not solved.  If it was solved you would know the cause of the issue, and that would tell you why the fix worked.  It would possibly give a solution that someone could use who does not have an upgrade path.  Also, a better practice for your original desire (to have the SQL server as a domain member server) would be to build a new SQL server as a member of the domain, then migrate the databases, services and apps to that new server.  Then test, sync database, and switch to the new server.  The original server remains as a rollback option until you're up and running on new.